# Can I use a subsequence to show continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

More specifically if $f$ is a function on $X$ and for some $x_{0} \in X$, if every sequence $x_n$ which converges to $x_{0}$, contains a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n_{k}})=f(x_{0})$ is that enough to say $f$ is continuous at $x_0$?

Thank You

Comment: You probably mean continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: Yes thank you for the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ (we are working in the reals or in some metric space, I assume, by your choice of the tags calculus and real analysis ) ,then this means there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists a point $x$ with $d(x,x_0) < \delta$ and $d(f(x_0), f(x)) \ge \varepsilon$.

Picking such a point $x_n$ of $X$ for $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ we get a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x_0$ but such that $d(f(x_n), f(x_0) \ge \varepsilon$.
This distance property also holds for all subsequences, so no subsequence of $(x_n)$ can have $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x_0)$.

So if $X$ is a metric space, then the "subsequence condition" indeed will give continuity at $x_0$.